# Считывание жеста пользователя (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

### Unity.

На сцене у меня есть одна или несколько линий разной формы. Пользователь, при помощи касаний по экрану, пытается провести точно такую же линию поверх данной. Если игрок провел максимально точно и не пропустил ни одной линии, то ему дается большее кол-во очков, и наоборот. Как можно реализовать расчет точности? Какую систему и алгоритм вы можете предложить?

### Мой метод.

Я пришел к тому, что вместо линии можно использовать `Line Renderer` с коллайдерам которые расположены у своих линий. Для начала считываем `массив тачей` пользователя. Для каждой `точки массива`,попавшей в коллайдер линии, находим вершину к которой она ближе всего расположена. Складываем все минимальные расстояния и `находим среднее`. К среднему прибавляем `какой-либо_коэффициент*кол-во_пропущенных точек`. Так мы находим число, означающее неточность пользователя. Хотелось бы услышать ваши предложения, т.к. для меня данная система считывания не кажется правильной.

*Прикрепляю пример. Линии - красные, коллайдеры - желтые.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял сути твоей идеи, но если тебе надо проверять насколько много пользователь нарисовал фигуру, то можно сделать префабы фигур, которые будут хранить в себе "участки" с коллайдерами, которые ты будешь проверять. Т.е. делаешь список этих точек, в `Start()` ты список заполняешь этими точками, при `OnCollisionEnter2D()` с точкой ты ее удаляешь и в конце подсчитываешь количество оставшихся точек. Но лично я бы сделал каждую точку со своим показателем очков с помощью размера коллайдера, хранил все в списке `List<Point> Points`, сам `class Point` имел бы поле `public int Scores` который определялся бы в старт от размера коллайдера и сразу же в этом классе сделать обработчик касания пальца. При касании например заносишь в новый список `List<Point> TouchedPoints` наши точки и в конце с помощью цикла ты в общую сумму берешь `Scores` из `TouchedPoints` и суммируешь.

Ну, или можешь не удалять точки, а создать поле `bool IsTouched` и помечать пройденные точки. Потом проверять каждую точку из `Points`и сразу же суммировать. На твоем скрине левый объект мне показался пистолетом, так что вот, да. Мог непонятно написать, за это извиняюсь.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]